# Liferay 6.2 ga 5 - Upload SVG issues

Tags: tomcat, liferay

How can i upload a `SVG` image to `Liferay 6.2 ga 5`?
I changed my `portal-ext.properties` to include:

```
journal.image.extensions=.gif,.jpeg,.jpg,.png,.svg
dynamic.data.mapping.image.extensions=*
shopping.image.extensions=*
blogs.image.extensions=*
```

When I edit `webcontent` I'm always getting:

> Please enter a value with a valid extension (.gif,.jpeg,.jpg,.png).

Note: I'm using `TOMCAT 7.0`.

Someone faced such scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting in portal-ext.properties:

**mime.types.web.images=image/gif,image/jpeg,image/pjpeg,image/png,image/x-png,image/svg
dl.file.generic.extensions[image]=bmp,gif,jpeg,jpg,odg,png,svg**

Comment: I tried right now and the result maintains.
Currently have:
`freemarker.engine.restricted.variables=`

`journal.image.extensions=.gif,.jpeg,.jpg,.png,.svg`
`dynamic.data.mapping.image.extensions=*`
`shopping.image.extensions=*`
`blogs.image.extensions=*`
`mime.types.web.images=image/gif,image/jpeg,image/pjpeg,image/png,image/x-png,image/svg`
`dl.file.generic.extensions[image]=bmp,gif,jpeg,jpg,odg,png,svg`

Comment: Where are you uploading the SVG ? I just tried with those 2 settings in an empty portal, and didn't have any problem. I upload it to Documents and Media, then in the webcontent I use from the server.

Comment: I was trying to upload directly from the webcontent editor. If i upload the imagem from Documents and Media i get success like you did. 
Sorry, but i'm new at liferay, how can i upload the image to a image data type in webcontent? Or i have to use a documents and media type?

Comment: yeah, with this version I could only use SVG in the Documents and Media, not directly to an image type in webcontent, I get the same error msg, despite the settings in portal-ext.